# SOAP Post works with Postman but not with Java

Tags: java

I have a very strange thing going on.

My code gives me Connection Timeout when I call -> `SOAPMessage resp = conn.call(msg, url);`

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

So I thought my url for the request or login was wrong but I copy paste the msg from the

```
 LOGGER.info(msg);
```

**and paste it in the Postman and it works**, I get the response.

Any idea what might be causing this issue? This seems to be an issue only with the code.

```
public void updateTicket(String ticketID, String user, String password, String connection, String nameSpace, Map < String, Object > values, Map < String, Object > articleValues, Map < String, Object > dynamicFieldsValues) throws UnsupportedOperationException, SOAPException, IOException, Exception {

    // Create the connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection conn = scf.createConnection();

    // Create message
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage();

    // Object for message parts
    SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();

    SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();

    env.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    env.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    env.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
    env.addNamespaceDeclaration("con", nameSpace);

    SOAPBody body = env.getBody();

    SOAPElement ticketUpdate = body.addChildElement("TicketUpdate", "con");

    ticketUpdate.addChildElement("UserLogin", "con").addTextNode(user);
    ticketUpdate.addChildElement("Password", "con").addTextNode(password);
    ticketUpdate.addChildElement("TicketID", "con").addTextNode(ticketID);


    LOGGER.info("SOAP Request");

    LOGGER.info(msg);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    msg.writeTo(stream);

    URL url = new URL(connection);

    SOAPMessage resp = conn.call(msg, url);
```

Edit: The `connection` variable contains the correct SOAP endpoint

Comment: It's hard to tell without the stacktrace and the actual url. One thing you may want to try is to sniff the actual traffic by using Wireshark or Fiddler.